# What the meaning of the comma in this Python?

Tags: python

This code will create a spin on Python:

```
while True:
    for i in ["/", "-", "|", "\\", "|"]:
    print "%s\r" % i,
```

Can someone explain to me why we use the comma after "i" or in the line {print "%s\r" %i,"? When I remove the comma after "i", it does not spin anymore? I want to know what how this comma works?